# How to select data via partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have a partial view that returns a list of users address's, I need the user to be able to select one, then when they press "submit" along with the other details it takes the details from the selected address returns it to the controller, from there I know how to assign it where I want. How would I do this? Examples and help appreciated

Here is my controller for creating the order, view beneath;

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values, string id)
    {

        var order = new Order();
        TryUpdateModel(order);

        //sets date and username
        order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
        order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;


        //Order gets saved
        storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                storeDB.SaveChanges();


                //Order gets processed
                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);

                //Save again, total not saving properly until now
                storeDB.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                    new { id = order.OrderId });
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Address And Payment";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OrderId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OrderDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PaymentTransactionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Total)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Username)

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h2>Address And Payment</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        @{Html.RenderAction("Listofaddresses", "Checkout");}


        <h2>Select Postage type</h2>


        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.PostageList, "-- Please select postage type --")


        <h2>Payment</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cardDetails.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardDetails.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardDetails.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardExpireMonth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardExpireMonth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardExpireMonth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardExpireYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardDetails.CardExpireYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
             </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cardDetails.Cvc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cardDetails.Cvc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardDetails.Cvc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model IEnumerable<T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.deliveryAddress>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div style="width: 180px">
        <div class="thumbnail">

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName) </p>

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)</p>

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</p>

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostalCode)</p>

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Address Class**

```
    public class deliveryAddress
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int AdressId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string UsersAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone home number is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Home Telephone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone mobile number is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to select one? Using radio buttons against each address?

Comment: A radio button would be what Im looking for yea, and then pass that specific Address back to the controller after submitting card details/postage @StephenMuecke

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model) { <label>@Html.RadioButton("Address", item.AdressId, new { id = "" }) <div style="width: 180px">.....</div></label>` and the value of `Address` in `FormCollection` will be the selected `AdressId`. But this is an awful way to do it. You should never use `FormCollection`. You should be using view models and strongly binding to those models.

Comment: Is there no way to return each value? E.g. name, address, city etc, or would I need to use a ViewModel to do that? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Why would you even consider that? (generating all that extra html and posting it all back again unchanged) Just get the address in the POST method based on the selected ID.

Comment: Because im a student and still doing ridiculously extra work to do the simple tasks! That sounds like it would work well, how would I do that @StephenMuecke ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111414/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-andre-queen).